# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Graduation review verdict: site is not ready for graduation at this time. While there is a fine community here, it is still too small to support graduation. Community review indicates the quality of questions and answers is mixed - questions are often vague or unresolved; this may resolve itself as the site grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is involved to recharge the Air Conditioning System?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6060/what-is-involved-to-recharge-the-air-conditioning-system)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Improving fuel economy in high-milage automatic transmission car](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5873/improving-fuel-economy-in-high-milage-automatic-transmission-car)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Volkswagen Jetta Oil Pan Change](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5931/volkswagen-jetta-oil-pan-change)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [1998 Chevy Lumina won’t start, crank, or click](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6076/1998-chevy-lumina-wont-start-crank-or-click)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [My automatic transmission slid to neutral while driving down the freeway. Can I just put it back in drive?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5966/my-automatic-transmission-slid-to-neutral-while-driving-down-the-freeway-can-i)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [WagonR refuses to start sometimes](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6006/wagonr-refuses-to-start-sometimes)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [2003 Acura TLS running hotter than usual](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/2003-acura-tls-running-hotter-than-usual)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why does my Toyota Camry Hybrid (2008) keep consuming tires?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6025/why-does-my-toyota-camry-hybrid-2008-keep-consuming-tires)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Fixing small scratches on the body paint](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/fixing-small-scratches-on-the-body-paint)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [1975 Honda XL 250 has erratic idle / high idle when it's cold out](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/1975-honda-xl-250-has-erratic-idle-high-idle-when-its-cold-out)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)